# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Let $b_{n}$ be a subsequence of $a_n$. Prove that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}$ converges.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ convergent $\rightarrow$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ convergent $\rightarrow$ $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent $\rightarrow \{b_{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent

$\rightarrow b_{n}$ cauchy sequence $\rightarrow$ $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists M$ s.t. $|b_m-b_n|< \varepsilon$ for $m\ge n \ge M$ $\rightarrow |\sum_{i=n+1}^mb_i| < \varepsilon$

I think this step is wrong because $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is cauchy sequence, but $|\sum_{i=n+1}^m 1/n| \not< \varepsilon$.

How can I proceed from here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to use Cauchy's condition, use it for the series, not the sequence. If $b_k=a_{n_k}$, then $|b_k|+|b_{k+1}|+...+|b_m|= |a_{n_k}|+|a_{n_{k+1}}|+...+|a_{n_m}|\leq |a_{n_k}|+|a_{n_k+1}|+...+|a_{n_m}|<\epsilon$ for $n_k$ and $n_m$ large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If  $(b_{n})_n$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)_n$ then there is a strictly increasing function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^+$ to $\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $b_n=a_{f(n)}$. Then for any positive integer $N$, $f(N)\geq N$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |b_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^N |a_{f(n)}|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{f(N)} |a_{n}|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|\in \mathbb{R}.$$
What may we conclude about the absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I revised my answer.

Comment: how did you do the inequality in the middle, $\sum |a_{f(n)}| \le \sum |a_n|$?

Comment: The sum on the right contains all the terms of the sum on the left (recall that $f$ is increasing.